# clean code duplicate at many pages flutter

Tags: flutter

am looking to clean my code

such : menu items it's at every page how to set it

into one dart file  and include it later !!

like PHP

```
<?php include('1.dart'); ?>
```

am looking to do it with duplicate Containers at pages

that's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly like that,but you can make a Widget that suits your needs,then create an instance of it in other widgets by importing the .dart file and using it without writing all its code.
I can give you an example:

---

I need a specific `Container` or `Card` of any other widget that will need to be replicated.What I would do in this scenerio is create a new `.dart` file and name it after what I need-for example a Social Network post:

```
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  Post();

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {

  _PostState(){
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
}
```

---

I would write the code that I need to replicate in here then import it inside my `home.dart` like this:

```
import 'package:app/widgets/post.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  Home();

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  _HomeState(){

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Post post = new Post(//here you can construct the post with your data);
}
```